# tensorflow save output layer results for review

Tags: tensorflow

Working on simple softmax tensorflow classification with 4 features/inputs and 3 outputs.

To save results : input vs predicted output vs actual output , doing tf.concat across all tensors and print(Tensor.eval()) to review results.

Wondering in real use case what are the best ways to review results which are not scalar(So tensorboard scalar not an option) , but N-D type results. Any tool  to plot graph with tensor outputs? Dump to file(Data could be huge , hard to analyze)? Dump to database? Depends on real time requirements , but looking for any tools to plug in output of tensorflow.

Please share thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course request any tensor and get it back in numpy format, from there you can do what you like with it.

Tensorboard is the main visualization tool in tensorflow. It allows you to display scalar and histogram data types, as well as images and audio clips as you train.

Here are a few images from tensorboard of scalar values, distribution, and histogram

- Scalar values are showing error rates
- Distribution shows the distribution of gradient magnitudes
- Histogram shows a 3D histogram of gradient magnitudes over time

[image]

[image]

[image]